# iOS 11UICollectionView scroll to top gets stuck with large titles

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, ios11

The title is a mouthful, but here is what is happening. In iOS 11 when you have a navigation bar with large titles then you scroll down a ways and tap the status bar it will scroll to the top. When it scrolls to the top it gets stuck scrolling *past* the top.

It looks super messed up, here is an example after it scrolled to the top. It scrolled so far it started pulling the refresh control! [image: scrolled too far]

Has anyone seen this and been able to fix it? Mail has a large title and doesn't have the problem, though it is likely not a `UICollectionView`

Here is a gif of it happening:
[image]

As far as code goes it is as simple as I can make it:

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "fakeCell", for: indexPath) as? UICollectionViewCell
        cell?.backgroundColor = [UIColor.black, .blue, .red, .green, .yellow][indexPath.row % 5]
        return cell!
    }

}
```

Comment: I assume the above is vanilla code, but might still be worth showing.

Comment: Try returning `false` from [scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619378-scrollviewshouldscrolltotop?language=objc) and put your own scroll-to-top code in there.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution:

- in viewDidLoad - set extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
- in storyboard - pin collectionView top constraint to superview top with constant = 0 (collectionView will be under navigationbar when translucent)

After that if you tap on statusbar, collectionView stops in the right place.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as you!

In my case I managed to solve this problem by  making the navigation bar **transluent** :

[image]

Do not ask me why it works... I have no idea

(I've got the idea there https://stackoverflow.com/a/50639773)

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem like this. In my case the table view was added to a view controller and the table view's top was assigned to safe area. I changed the table view to super view's top. It was working as expected. This may help in ur case if the collection view is added to the view controller. 
Thanks.